# Adding header/footer to GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a hard time to design a `GridView` layout with header and footer like this:

[image: layout]

What I did is, create a `ListView` with just one item which is the `GridView` and add the header/footer using `addHeaderView()` and `addFooterView()`. The problem is that the `GridView` doesn't show the whole items. I've disabled the `GridView` scrolling using:

```
  gridview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Is there a way to show the make the `GridView` show all items? I've tried setting the height of the `GridView` to `wrap_content` but it doesn't work. Here is the layout for the `GridView` :

```
<GridView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:background="@color/main_gray"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center">

</GridView>
```

I know it is not right to put gridview inside a listview but the client requested for this kind of layout..

Comment: Why don't you add the gridview in layout and add two views top and bottom

Comment: the header and footer will not be included when it's scrolled

Comment: @DanielJohnGomez, have your problem solved?

Comment: @DanielJohnGomez got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good starting point :

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java

This class handles headers very well, exaclty the same way as `ListView` does.

You should manage to add footer handling as well, but it'a a bit more complicated, as you have to put placeholders depending on the number of elements you have in your `Gridview`.
And as the height of a `Gridview` row is based on the height of its last element, you will have to get the height of the last item of your `GridView`

```
convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
convertView.setMinimumHeight(lastItemHeight);
```

I use this to calculate last item height. It's probably not optimal, but it works for my use cases :

```
View v = mAdapter.getView(adjPosition, convertView, parent);

//measure last item height for placeholders before footer views
v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                lastItemHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
lastItemHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Answer (score -1):

Check This Out Hope it Resolve Your Problem

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#AAFFDD" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"
        android:background="@color/main_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FADFAE" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: same, if i do it this way, the header and footer will not be included when scrolling

Comment: i have try this before its work fine , Give weight of .97 to gridview it will works as you want .

Answer (score -1):

gridview class does not provided methods addheaderview() and addfooterview() ,
you can take linearlayout with orientation vertical and can add custom header via inflating a layout then inflate gridview after that footer view .

Comment: This answer just does not help at all